# Log4j não cria log no Docker

Tags: docker

Estou começando agora com Docker e estou fazendo alguns testes com uma aplicação pequena.

Consigo subir a aplicação no Docker porém, tenho o log4j configurado para gerar os arquivos de log em um path específico, `/var/log/teste`. Quando subo a aplicação na minha máquina - estou usando Cent OS 7 - o log é gerado, quando dou um `docker build .`, o jetty sobe sem erros, mas não gera log.

Segue meu Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.3.1-jdk-7

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir /var/log/teste
RUN chmod 777 -R /var/log/teste

RUN mvn clean install

EXPOSE 8080

RUN mvn jetty:run
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão para me ajudar?

Comment: `docker build` apenas cria a imagem, você está criando/rodando um container? Por exemplo, se fizer um `docker ps`, consegue ver se tem container rodando? Se não, faça algo como `docker run <parametros> <nome-da-sua-imagem>` para iniciar um novo container, se já tiver algum criado, faça `docker start <nome-container>`

Answer (score 0):

Os logs não são criados por que não há um *container* rodando. [`build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) constrói uma imagem e a deixa disponível, para que seja possível usá-la para criar *containers*. Os logs de construção da aplicação, o jetty rodando no `build` e tudo o mais é apenas o comando criando a imagem, ou seja, baixando as dependências (conforme especificado no `RUN` do `Dockerfile`, etc.) e não necessariamente rodando o *container*. Observe que até então não temos um *container*, já que `build` é um comando de imagem, não de *container*. Veja nos [tópicos](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/) o que é de um e de outro.

Para executar todo o fluxo que pretende, vamos considerar que você construiu a sua imagem da seguinte forma (assumindo que você está no diretório em que está o `Dockerfile`):

```
docker build -t jetty-log4j .
```

Se a construção for realização com sucesso, ao listar as imagens ([`docker images`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/) você terá algo assim:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jetty-log4j               <none>              81a458346fd6        5 minutes ago       605 MB
```

Criada a imagem agora temos que criar um *container* e rodá-lo e para isto temos o [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). Este cara primeiro cria um *container* e depois o inicia. Ele é a combinação do [`create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) e [`start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/), apenas para facilitar nossa vida :)

Então, para criarmos e iniciarmos nosso *container* podemos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
docker run --name jetty-log4j-test \
    -d \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    jetty-log4j
```

Isto irá criar um container chamdo `jetty-log4j` e rodá-lo. É neste momento que o seu log será criado, pois agora de fato há um *container* sendo executado, então sua aplicação está rodando.

Se quiser executar primeiro o [`create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/) e depois o [`start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/), pode fazer assim:

```
docker create --name jetty-log4j-test \
    -d \
    -p 8080:8080 \
    jetty-log4j
```

E depois:

```
docker start jetty-log4j-test
```

O [`start`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/) pode ser usado daqui em diante, não precisar usar o [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) novamente, já que você já tem o *container* criado, só se quiser outro *container* da mesma imagem.

Agora podemos fazer o [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) para ver se o *container* realmente está rodando e teremos algo assim:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9c01fb0b739a        jetty-log4j                  bash                   17 seconds ago       Up 16 seconds       8080/tcp            jetty-log4j-test
```

É depois deste passo que poderemos notar o log no *path* configurado, já que é agora que de fato temos um *container* rodando, e não apenas uma imagem.

Para parar o *container* basta fazer isto:

```
docker stop jetty-log4j-test
```

Para o demais comandos, veja na documentação tudo disponíve na [cli](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/).